# Unable to connect to Microsoft Access Database (C++)

Tags: c++, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been going trough tons of articles and forums about this and I still have not found my solution. Even though there are several posts of this on this website aswell.

They state these things as answers:

- Install this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
  I'm unable to install the x86 version, becouse I have office x64 2010. I did however installed the x64 version of that package.
- Install this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734
  I've tried it, no results.
- Make sure you application is targeted correctly (i.e. x86)
  I'm 100% sure my application is 32 bit.

My work environment is as follows:

- Visual Studio 2012 professional
- Coding language is C++
- Microsoft Office 2010
- Windows 8 x64

This is the code that I'm using:

```
class Credential
{
  public:
     TCHAR CredentialID[3];
     TCHAR CredentialName[255];

     BEGIN_COLUMN_MAP(Credential)
        COLUMN_ENTRY(1, CredentialID)
        COLUMN_ENTRY(2, CredentialName)
     END_COLUMN_MAP()
};
```

and this:

```
try
{
    CDataSource ds;
    CSession session;
    ATL::CCommand<CAccessor<Credential>> cust;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        Console_Output("Can't start COM!?\n");
        return;
    }

    hr = ds.OpenFromInitializationString(L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MPFDatabase.accdb;");
    Console_Output("%d\n", hr);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        Console_Output("Can't open Nwind\n");
        return;
    }

     hr = session.Open(ds);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        Console_Output("Can't open Nwind SESSION\n");
        ds.Close();
        return;
    }

    TCHAR mySQL[] = "SELECT * FROM Credential";

    hr = cust.Open(session, mySQL);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        Console_Output("Can't open Nwind TABLE\n");
        session.Close();
        ds.Close();
        return;
    }

    while(cust.MoveNext() == S_OK)
    {
        Console_Output("%s -- %s\n", cust.CredentialID, cust.CredentialName);
    }

    cust.Close();
    session.Close();
    ds.Close();
}
catch(std::exception &Ex)
{
    Console_Output("ex: %s\n", Ex.what());
}
```

I get to the point where it calls ds.OpenFromInitializationString but then it either stops my application without any notification whatsoever (no exception too). Or I get to the point where it would print in my console "Can't open Nwind\n".

These 2 results depend on what I've installed of the suggested answers.

I've tried absolute and relative paths for my Data Source.
I'm 100% sure it is not locked or something similar. I've created the database myself and it consists of only 2 tables, nothing special.

If I list my providers in windows powershell I get these providers:

- SQLOLEDB
- MSQLAP
- MSQLAP
- MSDataShape
- SQLNCLI11
- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
- ADsDSOObject
- SQLNCLI11 Enumerator
- Windows Search Data Source
- MSDASQL
- MSDASQL Enumerator
- SQLOLEDB Enumerator
- MSDAOSP

So the ace engine is indeed installed as you can see.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that it is concerning a local accdb file made in ms access 2010 on my computer. In case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that tags stand alone and can not be combined to create concepts.  That is, combining `[microsoft]`, `[access]` and `[database]` doesn't mean the same thing as the `[ms-access]` tag.  Always be sure to read the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gord has said. . . 
How do you have a 32 bit application running on a 64 bit machine? First thing is to try to get those in sync.

I had a similar problem with access (but the application type was setup properly for me and I was in c#) so I will mention the three things that had an affect relating to the compatability problem as we had the same error message.

Goto the properties tab under Build. Then change Platform Target from the default Any CPU to x64 or x86. For me this was not optional it must be set to the right one when I deployed, but it worked fine under any CPU when I was debugging locally.

I also had to install the AccessDataBaseEngine_x64 which it sounds like you have already.

The next thing to check is your connection string. 
For me my local was x86 and my server was x64.

For me both of these two worked with some playing around on this Jet and ACE settings:

```
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\your pathj\Database.accdb;";

        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\your path\Database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

and I passed the connectionString instead of putting it into the field directly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine -- a.k.a. "ACE" -- installed (as part of 64-bit Office 2010) and you are 100% sure that your application is running as 32-bit then I'm 100% sure that it won't work. 32-bit applications cannot use the 64-bit ACE driver, and 64-bit applications cannot use the 32-bit ACE driver. So, your choices are:

- configure your application to run as 64-bit and use the existing 64-bit ACE driver, or
- replace the 64-bit version of Office with the 32-bit version and run your application as 32-bit.